# How to change declared body type from String to custom DTO type in Swagger using SpringBoot and SpringFox

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-ui, spring-restcontroller, springfox

I have a rest controller with one method. This method takes one `String` argument  annotated as `@RequestBody`. For some reason not mentioned here, I'm forced to use type `String` and manually convert it to `TestDTO`. From the API's consumer point of view body is type of `TestDTO` and I want to show this type in SwaggerUI.

Unfortunately (which is quite obvious) swagger shows that body is type of `String`. Look at the picture below.

[image]

What I want to achieve is to have `String` body in java code and `TestDTO` in swagger code. How can I force Swagger to show it? I tried to find annotations and its properties, but failed.

Rest controller code below:

```
@RestController
@Api(tags = { "test" }, description = "test related resources")
public class TestController {

    @Autowired
    ObjectMapper mapper;

    @RequestMapping(path = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void confirm(@RequestBody String requestBody) throws IOException {

        //do sth with body

        TestDTO dto = mapper.readValue(requestBody, TestDTO.class);

        //do sth with dto
    }

}

class TestDTO{

    private String value;

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. Two changes need to be made.

First, like in @Dave Pateral's answer `@ApiImplicitParams` must be added

```
@RestController
@Api(tags = { "test" }, description = "test related resources")
public class TestController {

    @Autowired
    ObjectMapper mapper;

    @ApiImplicitParams({
        @ApiImplicitParam(name = "requestBody", required = true,
            dataType = "TestDTO", paramType = "body")
    })
    @RequestMapping(path = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void confirm(@RequestBody String requestBody) throws IOException {

        //do sth with body

        TestDTO dto = mapper.readValue(requestBody, TestDTO.class);

        //do sth with dto
    }
}
```

And then implicit Model must be registered in the docket, minimal working example below

```
@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private TypeResolver typeResolver;

    @Bean
    public Docket docket() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .additionalModels(typeResolver.resolve(TestDTO.class));
    }

}
```

And the result is
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try put this annotation on your method:

```
@ApiImplicitParam(name = "test", value = "testDTO", required = true, dataType = "TestDTO")
```

Comment: It didn't help. Another param appeared in swagger ui.